# Using custom exception in Java

Tags: java, bluej

I am trying to throw my custom exception in java but currently I have had no luck. I have two classes a readWrite class which allows the user to enter the file name and a text to be wrote to the file (via the constructor). It has three methods, write, read and a writeToFile which validates if the file ends in .txt if it does now it should throw my custom exception class stating that "Sorry but this system only accepts .txt files" which I have created in a toString() method in my custom exception. I can not seem to make it work, below is the code, some might be able to help, I hope I have explained properly as I am new to Java, note I have commented out some code as I was trying a few different things to make it work

**ReadWrite.java**

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadWrite
{   
    private final String file;
    private final String text;

    public ReadWrite(String file, String text)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.file=file;
        this.text=text;   
    }

    private void write() //throws InvalidFileException 
    {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

            writer.write(text);
            writer.write('\n');
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }

    public boolean writeToFile() 
    {    
        boolean ok;

        try{        
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);       
            {   
                if(file.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt"))
                {  
                    write();
                    ok = true;
                } //if end
                else{
                    ok=false;
                    //throw new InvalidFileException();
               } //else end
            }
        } //try end
        catch(IOException e) {
           ok=false; 
        } // catch end         
        //catch (InvalidFileException e){

            //System.out.println(e.toString());
        //}
        return ok;
    }

    public void read(String fileToRead)
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToRead));
            String line = reader.readLine();

            while(line != null) {
               System.out.println(line);
               line = reader.readLine();
            }// while end

            reader.close();

        }//try end
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {                  
            System.out.println(fileToRead + " the system can not     find the file specified");                  
        }  //catch end
        catch(IOException e) {                          
            e.printStackTrace();

        } //catch end
    }
}
```

**InvalidFileException.java**

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.*;

public class InvalidFileException extends Exception
{
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class InvalidFileException
     */
    public InvalidFileException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ("Sorry but this system only accepts .txt files");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't show the code where you're using any of the methods in `ReadWrite`, and the line where you would throw your custom exception is commented out. Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your problem.

Comment: How did you implement that? Where is the method that throws the `InvalidFileException` and where do you catch it within your code?

Comment: Just a guess:  Java won't generate a default, no-arg constructor if you create one or more explicit constructors with arguments.

Comment: The e.toString() won't print anything. Use e.printStackTrace() or e. getMessage()

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
private void write() throws InvalidFileException {
try {
    if(!file.getName().endsWith(".txt") {
        throw new InvalidFileException(".txt files only.");
    }
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

    writer.write(text);
    writer.write('\n');
    writer.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    // handle exception please.
}
```

Please note, that you have to override the "getMessage()" Method of Exception in order to print your custom message. Or set it in the super() call.

Overriding the toString() method makes your super() call and therefore your custom (detail) message passed to the exception (in my example ".txt files only.") obsolete, because this string won't be printed anymore.

Comment: **Never** leave catch block empty. You're just asking for problems.

Comment: Basicly you are right. This code is nearly an example to demonstrate a solution to the given problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below is your requirement:

> it does not it should throw my custom exception class stating that
>   "Sorry but this system only accepts .txt files"

I think you got confused because of `toString`. You really don't need that `toString` method. You correctly implemented a `InvalidFileException` which accepts a `String` argument.

So, now all you need is `throw new InvalidFileException("Sorry but this system only accepts .txt files");` or use whatever String message you want while throwing `InvalidFileException`.

**Please note,** if you are throwing an exception from a method and catching it in same method looks illogical unless you are doing because APM (application performance monitoring) tools logging purpose.

As other note, if you are throwing exception like this then you need to add a `throw` statement in your method signature indicating that this method "may" throw so-and-so exception. So, that called of that method can either re-throw or catch it.

If you are catching the exception somewhere then use `getMessage` method on the exception object and you will get same message as you placed while throwing the exception, in this case - "*Sorry but this system only accepts .txt files*"

Answer (score -1):

`InvalidFileException` extends `Exception` but you only ever try to catch `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException`. I think you meant to have `InvalidFileException` extend `IOException`.